# Load an image from a XHR request and then pass it to the server

Tags: javascript

I want to load an image with an XHR request from a website and pass it to the server.

I made this code to display the image I downloaded :

```
#Generated from coffeescript
GoogleDrivePicker.prototype.getUrl = function(file) {
  var accessToken, xhr;
  accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  xhr.onload = (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      var blob, reader;
      blob = new Blob([xhr.responseText], {
        type: 'image/jpeg'
      });
      blob.name = 'Test.jpg';
      blob.type = "image/jpeg";
      reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('loadend', function(e) {
        return $('.col-md-5 > img:nth-child(1)').attr('src', e.target.result);
      });
      return reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    };
  })(this);
  return xhr.send();
};
```

The result is just blank. I can see, on the developer console, than the image is correctly loaded.

I'm passing the image by using fileupload like this `fileupload('add', {files: [blob], filename: 'blob.jpg'})`.

I suppose the image is malformated because I'm having this error :

```
["Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `identify /tmp/mini_magick20160212-1-1xik1k5.jpg` failed with error:\nidentify.im6: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf `/tmp/mini_magick20160212-1-1xik1k5.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/316.\n"
```

When I look at the image with a text editor, it starts by :

```
����^@^PJFIF^@^A^A^@^@^A^@^A^@^@��^ARCAMERA       : E995V1.6
```

And it's on the UTF-8 format.

On the original file, it's :

```
^@^PJFIF^@^A^A^@^@^A^@^A^@^@^ARCAMERA       : E995V1.6
```

On latin1 format.

I tried to convert the file format without success.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the response type as a blob with `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` when downloading the file:

```
  function download(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
      if (event.target.readyState == 4) {
        if (event.target.status == 200 || event.target.status == 0) {
          //Status 0 is setup when protocol is "file:///" or "ftp://"
          var blob = this.response;
          callback(blob);
          //Use blob to upload the file
        } else {
          console.error('Unable to download the blob');
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
```

Then use the following code to upload the blob object, using `send(blob)` method of the request:

```
function upload(url, blob, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (event.target.readyState == 4) {
      if (event.target.status == 200) {
        //Blob uploaded to server
        callback(true);
      } else {
        //An error occurred when uploading file
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open('PUT', url, true);
  xhr.send(blob);
}
```

And finally use the functions:

```
download('http://example.com/file.jpg', function(blob) {
  upload('http://example.com/upload', blob, function() {
    //finished
  });
});
```

[Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) for more details on how to receive and send binary data.